# Using “de” or “en” to indicate that an object is made out of some material

Tags: prépositions

Which one is correct? **en** or **de**?

> Un verre **de/en** cristal.
>
> Une veste **de/en** cuir.

Comment: Les deux se disent, je ne pense pas qu'il y ait de différence de sens et pour moi les deux sont corrects. Des recherches google sur plusieurs exemples confirment mon impression : l'expression de la matière se fait plus souvent avec **de** qu'avec **en**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both **de** and **en** can introduce a *complément circonstanciel de matière*.
The *Trésor de la langue française* says that **en** is more strongly attached to a material than **de** (***En** marque plus précisément la matière que **de***.)

- **de** belongs to a **higher level of language** : *épingles d'or*; *bulles d'air*; *pièces d'argent*
- only **de** can be used in **figurative** speech: *un lit de feuilles mortes; un homme de fer; des chevaux de bois* (but some exceptions, see below)

  - (Latouche, L'Héritier, Lettres amans, 1821, p. 100).

> Alors commencent ces hémorragies effrayantes, qui font de tous ces malades autant de fontaines **de** sang

**de** is used in **idioms**: *Un teint de lait; un ciel de plomb; un cœur de pierre; un visage de marbre; un cœur d'or; un regard de feu; un bras de fer* etc.

**en** is more common to introduce this material:

- Beauvoir, Mém. j. fille, 1958 p. 77.

> En fonte, en terre, en grès, en porcelaine, en aluminium, en étain, que de marmites, de poêles, de pot-au-feu, de fait-tout, de cassolettes, de soupières, de plats, de timbales, de passoires, de hachoirs, de moulins, de moules, de mortiers !

**en** is used in figurative speech only in these idioms (except these, **de** is always used in other figurative speech): *un tigre en papier, un garçon en or*. Note that the fictive material takes a real aspect here.

- (Aymé, op. cit., p. 199);

> Ah ! oui, ce qu'il était gentil, hein ? et doux et pas fier. Un garçon en or, ce petit saint François.

Answer (score 5):

The correct words are:

> Un verre en cristal

(Because *Un verre de cristal* would mean it is full of crystal, like *un verre d'eau*).

> Une veste en cuir

(Both could be accepted, but *Une veste de cuir* is almost a tongue twister and *Une veste en cuir* is pronounced *Une vest'en cuir*).

If you are looking for a general rule, I'm sorry, but it depends. Usually, you can say both and you will be understood, but there are (as always) exceptions. Your first example is one.

Comment: You'll find  shops selling des verres/des cendriers/des vases **de** cristal, and they're sold empty.
Here's [one](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Vase_de_cristal_d%27Ali%C3%A9nor.jpg) you won't find in the shops but in the Louvre.
Par contre on dira un verre **en** cristal de Baccara/de Murano/de Bohème... Mais je ne sais pas si c'est une question d'usage ou s'il y a une règle.

Comment: @Laure I would not consider one isolated contributor to be a safe source, even less when pointing to a file name.

Answer (score 4):

I would also say that both are acceptable answers and at least in spoken French, there is really no rule. A few more examples:

> Un piège **de** cristal (figurative)
>
> Un pont **de** pierre (non-figurative)
>
> Une table **en** bois
>
> La rockeuse **de** diamants (figurative)
>
> Une occasion **en** or (figurative)
>
> Des jambes **de** / **en** feu (I think **de** is better there)
>
> Une défense **en** carton

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

As everyone already said, both are allowed.

The only difference between the usage of *de/en* I found [is here (french link)](http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_19_de_en.shtml), and is about the figurative language.

In figurative language, we preferably use **de**, except (french language speciality) in the expression *en or*.

> Un cœur **de** pierre, une patte **de** velours.
>
> Un cœur **en** or.

Comment: Certes mais : « la parole est d’or ».